# Error sentencia MYSQL #1064

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE procesar_pagos(numbole varchar(10),numrecibo varchar(10),numdoc varchar(8),codven varchar(2),codcli varchar(2),valpago decimal(12,2),comentario VARCHAR(100),iniciales varchar(2));
    BEGIN
        DECLARE numdocpago VARCHAR(14);
        DECLARE cwregistros INT;
        DECLARE cwtotal DECIMAL(12,2);
        DECLARE nuevo_saldo DECIMAL(12,2);
        DECLARE saldo_actual DECIMAL(12,2);
                
        DECLARE tmp_numdoc VARCHAR(8);
        DECLARE tmp_valdoc DECIMAL(12,2);
        DECLARE a INT;
        SET a = 1;
        SET numdocpago = concat(iniciales,codven,numbole);
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temporal(id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, numboleta varchar(10),numrecibo varchar(10),codvendedor varchar(2),codcliente varchar(10),comentario varchar(100),numdoc varchar(8), valpago decimal(12,2));
        SET cwtotal = (SELECT sum(valpago) FROM pagos_tmp WHERE codcliente = codcli);                 
        SET cwregistros = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagos_tmp WHERE codcliente = codcli);
        
        IF cwregistros > 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_temporal(numboleta,numrecibo,codvendedor,codcliente,numdoc,valpago,comentario) SELECT numboleta,numrecibo,codvendedor,codcliente,numdoc,valpago,comentario FROM pagos_tmp WHERE codcliente = codcli;
            INSERT INTO pagosprov (n_comproba,recibocaja,numfactura,vendedor,cliente,fecha,valor,concepto) values (numboleta,numrecibo,numdoc,codvendedor,codcliente,now(),valpago,comentario);
            
            WHILE a <= cwregistros DO
                SELECT numdoc,valpago INTO tmp_numdoc,tmp_valpago FROM tbl_temporal WHERE id = a;
                SELECT saldo INTO saldo_actual FROM encabeza WHERE n_comproba = tmp_numdoc;
                
                SET nuevo_saldo = saldo_actual - tmp_valpago;
                UPDATE encabeza SET saldo = nuevo_saldo WHERE n_comproba = tmp_numdoc;
                
                SET a=a+1;
            END WHILE;
            
            DELETE FROM pagos_tmp WHERE codcliente = codcliente;
            TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_temporal;
            SELECT pagosprov.n_comproba,pagosprov.numfactura,pagosprov.cliente,pagosprov.valor FROM pagosprov WHERE pagosprov.n_comproba = numbole;
        ELSE
            SELECT 0;
        END IF;
    
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Buen dia, estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado, desde phpmyadmin, pero genera este error

Comment: Hola, desarrolla tu problema editando la pregunta mencionando qué intentas hacer y como llegaste al problema. Pon toda parte de código en una sección de código para facilitar la lectura. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: Gracias Abraham, lo haré para la proxima, ya solucioné, en la linea donde se define "CREATE PROCEDURE XXXX( AAAAAA)", al final le colocaba PUNTO Y COMA, se lo quité y funcionó.

Comment: @FranciscoVillalta la solución si gustas debe ir en la zona de respuestas por favor, anexo deberías editar tu pregunta con el error